# Simple PHP Array Replace Text

Tags: php, arrays, translate

Simple Question

I need to change second part of array to first.

```
$LANG = array (
'Completed' => 'Complété',
'Estimate updated' => 'Devis actualisé',
);
```

to

```
$LANG = array (
'Completed' => 'Completed',
'Estimate updated' => 'Estimate updated',
);
```

I try array_splice but without sucess.
Could some one help, i need to rewrite 500 lines.

ty

Comment: array keys as values???

Comment: Sorry, it is unclear what you are asking for. Please use the `edit` button below your question to revise the text and add a more precise explanation what it is you want to do. What do you mean by "first / second part of the array"?

Comment: simple

$LANG = array (
'phrase1' => 'phrase1',
'phrase2' => 'phrase2',
);

Comment: @MatheusVieira, Check out my answer

Comment: @frayne-konok tks but how to output array just the same way input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want to array keys as values,

**Using array functions:**

```
$out = array_combine(array_keys($LANG), array_keys($LANG));
print_r($out);
```

**Use foreach:**

```
foreach($LANG as $key => $val){
    $LANG[$key] = $key;
}

print_r($LANG);
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [Completed] => Completed
    [Estimate updated] => Estimate updated
)
```

Comment: how to output like the input, using php syntax

Comment: input is an array and output is the `printed` or `var_dumped` version.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this $key key  $row value

```
foreach($LANG as $key=>$row)
{

  $LANG [$key]=$key;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($LANG );
```

Comment: how to output like the input, using php syntax

Answer (score 0):

If you define a translation array you can use a simple foreach and replace the value:

```
$trans = [
    'Complété' => 'Completed', 
    'Devis actualisé' => 'Estimate updated'
];

$LANG = [
    'Completed' => 'Complété',
    'Estimate updated' => 'Devis actualisé',
];

foreach($LANG as $key => $value)
{
    $LANG[$key] = $trans[$value];
}
```

With this you can translate the values without worrying about the array keys and even have multiple translation languages.

Then `$LANG` will have the following values:

```
$TRANS = [ 
    'Completed' => 'Completed'
    'Estimate updated' => 'Estimate updated'
]
```

Comment: tks but isnt this i'm looking for, i have only lang with 500 phrase and need to output the same way the array input